# How can I change the colour of an element I have created using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the colour of an element I have created using JavaScript. The information in this element is populated from data in a database.

```
var done = orders[i][2]; 
var id = orders[i][0];
id_and_name = JSON.stringify(id_and_name);
content = content + "<div onClick='loadOrder("+id_and_name+")' class='btn btn-lg btn-info' 
id= '"+id+"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> 
ID: "+orders[i][0]+"</br>Name: " + orders[i][1]+"</div>";
    if (done == 0){
        alert("order not done");
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
        alert(id);
    }else{
        alert("order done");
        document.getElementById(id).style.color = "green";
        alert(id);
    }

document.getElementById("main_content").innerHTML = content;
```

The code works without syntax errors when I remove the document.getElementById lines and runs through the appropriate branch. When I include these lines, I get a syntax error : VM882:125 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null(…).

Can I not change the colour of elements that I have created using javascript in this way. If not why?, and what method should I be using.

I have also checked what the value of id is with alert(id) and they are fine. Both are strings e.g.: "43" and "44". I have also tried to replace document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red"; with document.getElementById("43").style.color = "red"; and I get the same error.  When I remove the line the elements are created with the correct ID but of course i cannot change the colour then.

Comment: That error indicates that `document.getElementById(id)` is not returning anything (it's null). So, you need to double-check that you have an element with an id that is identical to whatever the `id` variable is.

Comment: You can also just add a string with a html style attribute that contains the css for the element to the html strings you're adding anyway.

Comment: Why are you coloring an element after you create it when you already have all the information necessary to color it when you create it?  You're jumping through hoops for no reason.  Just add the appropriate style at the time you create the element (i.e. use a class).  The problem is however that you have not actually added `content` to the document anywhere, so your new `div` does not actually exist

Comment: You haven't inserted the element into the DOM, so you can't get it with `getElementById`. This would be a lot easier if you started created actual elements with `createElement` instead of working with strings and inline javascript.

Comment: ah that happens later. with this.    document.getElementById("main_content").innerHTML = content; I have re-ordered it. And it works. Should I delete this post or can I accept that comment as an answer?

Comment: @MRKHANCOMUTILeader Doesn't make the element actually exist at the time this code is executed.  You are literally asking the document for an element that does not exist.  No surprise you can't color it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not inserted the element into the DOM yet, and as such you can't get it with `getElementById`.

This would go a lot easier if you actually create real elements, and not just strings

```
var done  = orders[i][2];
var id    = orders[i][0];
var id_and_name = JSON.stringify(id_and_name);
var div   = document.createElement('div');
var span  = document.createElement('span');
var text1 = document.createTextNode('ID: ' + orders[i][0]);
var text2 = document.createTextNode('Name: ' + orders[i][1]);
var br    = document.createElement('br');
var main  = document.getElementById("main_content");

div.className = 'btn btn-lg btn-info';
div.id = id;
div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    loadOrder(id_and_name);
},false);

span.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart';

if (done == 0) {
    div.style.color = "red";
} else {
    div.style.color = "green";
}

// later, insert the elements in the DOM

main.appendChild(div);
main.appendChild(span);
main.appendChild(text1);
main.appendChild(br);
main.appendChild(text2);
```

Comment: I've run across a number of people claiming that using DOM methods to create elements is slower than just using raw HTML.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Tibrogargan - In some cases it is, in other cases it's not, but creating actual elements makes it a lot easier to work with those elements, even if it means writing a few more characters.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solutions from the comments: One was to change the element after I had made it and the second one, the one I used, was to create CSS classes

```
var done = orders[i][2]; 
var id = orders[i][0];
id_and_name = JSON.stringify(id_and_name);
var button_colour = "red_background";
if (done == 1){
    button_colour = "green_background";
}

content = content + "<div onClick='loadOrder("+id_and_name+")' 
class='btn btn-lg btn-info "+button_colour+"' id= '"+id+"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> ID: "+orders[i][0]+"</br>Name: " + 
orders[i][1]+"</div>";
    document.getElementById("main_content").innerHTML = content;
```

The CSS:

```
.green_background{
    background-color: green;
    outline-color:black;
}

.red_background{
    background-color: red;
    outline-color:black;
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using DOM manipulation techniques (as @adeneo's answer demonstrates).  It's more readable for non-trivial cases, especially if you take advantage of jQuery's element creation functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, this means that when you try to call the property `style` on your element, the element is `null`. So this has nothing to do with the way you are trying to change the element's color.
This probably means that your `document` object doesn't contain an element with the `id` you provide to the `getElementById()` method.
What do you get when you try to call `document.getElementById(id)` with the `id` shown in the `alert` directly in the `Console`?

Comment: You could add an example of how to solve the problem to your answer.  It would make the answer more applicable